# What free OCR to use for receipt scanner app?

Tags: javascript, android, ocr, scanning, receipt

I'm making receipt scanner app for android in android studio. What free OCR should i use? The main information i'm trying to get from receipt is date, amount and currency.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs

```
import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';

Tesseract.recognize(
  'https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png',
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
})
```

You can use tesseract engine, also you can use tensorflow.js to create your own OCR model which will be complicated though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaScript as your main language, I think I've heard about a library called Tesseract.js. Dunno if it'll work but I think it's worth trying